# How to get vmnet8 subnet from within guest VM

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, vmware-fusion

I am building a demo VM (think of something similar to Hortonworks Sandbox VM) and want the VM to boot up with static IP such as 192.168.94.100

The vmnet8 has 192.168.94.0/24 in my Mac via VMware Fusion. But I also see a different subnet (let say Windows) such as 192.168.91.0/24. I am not sure if this is correct or depends on version.

So my question is: How to configure Linux VM (Centos) to boot up and assign itself a static IP in the subnet of vmnet8?

Obviously I could pick a random one but it could be in wrong subnet. Basically I am wondering if there is a way to get the subnet on the first boot and then lock it there as static, then do XYZ tasks (such as updating IP across all config files).